# Methods for simultaneously maximizing mean and minimizing variance

Tags: mathematical-statistics

Consider the following problem: I have two sets of lights and I am interested in the lifetime of the lamps. Set A has a high mean value but also a large variance. Set B has a lower mean but also a lower variance. I want to find 'the optimal combination' of mean and variance. Ideally, I want a high mean and low variance. Assume that we can control the variance and mean of the lifetime of the lamps with a certain parameter.

Now it makes sense to me to consider this as an optimisation problem; I want to choose my parameter such that the sum of variance and mean is minimal. But would this be a right way to deal with this problem?

Comment: Note first that your title and your post don't match. Variance of lifetime has dimensions time$^2$ and mean lifetime has dimensions of time, so the sum of the two quantities is dimensionally meaningless. More generally, I don't think you have given enough information on the set-up to make this a tractable problem.

Comment: I think in your title you mean "minimizing variance".

Comment: If you are going to add them you should use standard deviation instead of variance. So for example mean plus two standard deviations will give you the upper confidence bound for the lifetime of the lamp (assuming a normal distribution and at 95% sig level).

Comment: I agree that I should add the mean and the standard deviation. But would it make more sense to minimize a weighted average of the two?

Comment: I think you need to weight them, but you need to determine the cost of a lower mean, or the cost of a higher variance. For example, you might say that after 20% of the lights have expired, you need to replace all bulbs. You want to maximize the time to 20% failure (or whatever failure is sufficiently high).  I've heard of large buildings (e.g. factory) that put in double the required number of lights, and when half have failed, the factory is shut down for a day  and the lights are all replaced. The costs of the shut down should be taken into account.

Comment: (*previous comment deleted because it depends on this more fundamental issue*) ..... Are you trying to identify a criterion for choosing between A and B, or are you somehow able to trade off variability and mean and are looking for some optimum point on a frontier?

Comment: You certainly shouldn't *add* them because you want to minimize sd (or variance). There is the coefficient of variation: $\frac{\sigma}{\mu}$ or its sample version $\frac{s}{\bar{x}}$. You could try minimizing this.

Comment: I'll look intro minimizing the coefficient of variation, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

In Finance this is called a portfolio optimization problem. There is a vast lierature on the subject. Get youself a Finance 101 type textbook and find the section that deals with portfolio optimization and efficient frontiers. You will have to maximize a utility function (a simple mean-variance function is widely used, although there are other utility functions that have better theoretical properties). Fortunately you will find that you have to solve a simple quadratic program, but you wil need to apply constraints to the solution.